# Android: Different colours for different characters in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Thank you in advance for any responses.

I am trying to have an EditText in my Android application which has different colours for different characters which are typed in.

For e.g. Alphabet "A" should always be blue, alphabet "b" should always be green... so on.

So far, I have no been able to find a solution for it.
Please be kind enough to guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As was pointed out, you can apply Spannables to the text as it is entered. Something like this:

```
colorEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    String lastText = null;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        Log.d("", "lastText='" + lastText + "'");
        Log.d("", "s='" + s + "'");
        if (!s.toString().equals(lastText)) {
            lastText = s.toString();

            String res = "";
            char[] split = s.toString().toCharArray();
            for (char c : split) {
                String color = null;
                if (c == 'a') {
                    color = "red";
                } else if (c == 'b') {
                    color = "green";
                } else if (c == 'c') {
                    color = "blue";
                }
                // etc...
                if (color != null) {
                    res += "<font color=\"" + color + "\">" + c
                            + "</font>";
                } else {
                    res += c;
                }
            }
            int selectStart = colorEdit.getSelectionStart();
            int selectEnd = colorEdit.getSelectionEnd();
            colorEdit.setText(Html.fromHtml(res));
            colorEdit.setSelection(selectStart, selectEnd);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```

some things to note, I call `setText` which of course causes `onTextChanged` to run again, so I check that the text actually changed. Also, the cursor position was not saved correctly so I store and restore that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to wrap each letter in its own [ForegroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html). Add a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and apply the Spannables as the text is edited.

Answer (score 0):

You best shot is probably overriding `EditText` and writing your own `draw()`. But this way lies madness, as it usually is with overriding built-in view classes.

Comment: I was beginning to wonder that doing what you say might be my only choice. However I was also thinking about adding onClick listeners to a dummy image of EditText widget, then using the input text to replace characters with self-designed character images. Haven't thought this one through, but I reckon it might do the job as a last resort/Or your solution (Which is the right way, but yes, madness) .

Answer (score 0):

If I were You I would better use the `InputFilter` for it. `setText()` in `textWatcher{} onTextChange()` has some issues (eg. on a softkeyboard you can't select an national letter).

[Some issue with the TextWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485702/national-letter-selector-doesnt-appear)

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html)