# Underline a dynamically generated TextView in android

Tags: android, textview

I have a text view which has a certain text which is set in the xml file and in the strings.xml it is underlined.Now i am changing this textview form the contents in the edittext,i.e whatever the user is entering.To that text before setting it to the textview i am appending acertain string as well.I want this new string formed to be underlined with blue color and clickable. I tried using

```
 SpannableString phoneNum = new SpannableString(totalPhoneNum);
 phoneNum.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, totalPhoneNum.length(), 0);   
 phoneNum.setText(totalPhoneNum);
```

This is not working! Can i use this in onResume()
 I have no idea how to change the color of the underline to blue :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284264/how-to-set-underline-and-color-to-partly-text-at-one-time-on-textview
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout

Comment: mTextView.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG); this worked...i get the underline now...how do i change the color of the underline

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setColor(int)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To draw an Underline below the TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033316/to-draw-an-underline-below-the-textview-in-android)

Answer (score 4):

> There are three ways of underling the text in TextView.
>
> 1. [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)
> 2. [setPaintFlags();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setPaintFlags%28int%29) of TextView
> 3. [Html.fromHtml();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)
>
> Let me explain you all approaches :
>
> **1st Approach**
>
> For underling the text in TextView you have to use [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)
>
> ```
> String udata="Underlined Text";
> SpannableString content = new SpannableString(udata);
> content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, udata.length(), 0);
> mTextView.setText(content);
> ```
>
> **2nd Approach**
>
> You can make use of [setPaintFlags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setPaintFlags%28int%29) method of TextView to underline the text of TextView.
>
> For eg.
>
> ```
> mTextView.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
> mTextView.setText("This text will be underlined");
> ```
>
> You can refer constants of [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) class if you want to strike thru the text.
>
> **3rd Approach**
>
> Make use of `Html.fromHtml(htmlString);`
>
> ```
> String htmlString="<u>This text will be underlined</u>";
> mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
> ```

From:
[To draw an Underline below the TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033316/to-draw-an-underline-below-the-textview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
phoneNum.setText(Html.fromHtml("W : "+"<u><FONT COLOR=\"#80776b\" >"+Your text+"</Font></u>"));
```

Use color code what you want.

Comment: mTextView.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG); this worked...i get the underline now...how do i change the color of the underline.

Comment: you can use by using above code...where you can set the font color..as you want..

Comment: Need to change the color for just the underline

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
String txt = "<u style=\"text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000\">parragraph</u>";
phoneNum.setText(Html.fromHtml(txt));
```

this style will remove default underline and put a border bottom of 1 px as of color we pass.

Comment: mTextView.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG); this worked...i get the underline now...how do i change the color of the underline.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String text = "some string <u><font color=\"#00FF00\">some link</font></u>";
editText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: mTextView.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG); this worked...i get the underline now...how do i change the color of the underline

Answer (score 0):

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
public class TextDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new ViewWithRedDot(this));
    }
}

class ViewWithRedDot extends View {
    public ViewWithRedDot(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
        Typeface mType = Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.ITALIC);
        circlePaint.setTextSize(25);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        circlePaint.setTypeface(mType);
        canvas.drawText("Default Typeface", 50, 100, circlePaint);
        //
        circlePaint.setFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawText("Underline Text Flag", 50, 120, circlePaint);
        //
        circlePaint.setFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawText("Strike Thru Text Flag", 50, 140, circlePaint);
        //
        circlePaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawText("Anti Alias Flag", 50, 160, circlePaint);
        //
        circlePaint.setFlags(Paint.DEV_KERN_TEXT_FLAG);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawText("Dev Kern Text Flag", 50, 180, circlePaint);
        //
        circlePaint.setFlags(Paint.FAKE_BOLD_TEXT_FLAG);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawText("Fake Bold Text Flag", 50, 200, circlePaint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your layout xml file:

```
<TextView 
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:linksClickable="true" 
    android:textColorLink="#5e9baa" />
```