# Android - set color of text before typing text in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannable

I have EditText and 3 color selection boxes. I want to select a color and then start typing the text in EditText. Currently, I am only able to write the text, select it and then change the color of the text.

[image]

I have tried following but hasn't worked:

- Setting ForegroundColorSpan span to `Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE` in `TextWatcher` and `onCheckedChanged`
- Adding span to each character
- Remove all spans before adding new one

I have also tried to print the color of all the spans and it looks like the span is adding correctly but the EditText doesn't show the colors as per those spans. For example:

```
char = 0 (T)
    span 0 = Green
    span 1 = Green
char = 1 (E)
    span 0 = Green
    span 1 = Green
char = 1 (S)
    span 0 = Green
    span 1 = Red
char = 2 (T)
    span 0 = Green
    span 1 = Red

Output: EditText shows "TEST" in all green color
Note: selecting the text and applying span shows correct colors in EditText
```

--> layout/activity.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions" />
```

--> MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .......

    mEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(selectedColor), i, i, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

    Spannable spannable = this.mEditText.getText();
    int selStart = this.mEditText.getSelectionStart();
    int selEnd = this.mEditText.getSelectionEnd();

    if(group.getId() == R.id.radioGroupColor) {

        int selected = 0;
        switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.radioGreen:
                selected = Color.GREEN;
                break;
            case R.id.radioRed:
                selected = Color.RED;
                break;
            case R.id.radioBlue:
                selected = Color.BLUE;
                break;
        }

        if(selStart == selEnd) {
            // There is no selection 
        } else {
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(selected), selStart, selEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043767/android-different-colours-for-different-characters-in-edittext

Comment: Thanks @Jonik As mentioned in my updated question, I have already tried that but it doesn't work. I can't use HTML because the text colors are selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

> set color of text before typing text in EditText

**For Good Practice**,  I would like to suggest you to use [**`TextWatcher`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). You should override **`onTextChanged`** method.

> **`onTextChanged`** (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) -
>   This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count
>   characters beginning at start have just replaced old text that had
>   length before.

```
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Your Work

    }
```

Read [**`TextWatcher Example`**](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-textwatcher-example).

Comment: Thanks @IntelliJAmiya, I have updated my question. I have already tried using `TextWatcher` but the EditText doesn't show the colors correctly